# GLUT - what is imageloader.h and how can I get the correct one?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, glut

I'm currently learning the basic of how to map a texture in GLUT from this source:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/253361-texture-mapping-and-glutsolidsphere/

and I wonder what is that imageloader.h? the texturing procedure seem to be depending on it. I tried looking it up on Solution Explorer in Visual Studio 2012, no result. I googled it and it shows me different content of imageloader.h:

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-46.12/src/ImageLoader.h

https://github.com/zixtor/RM/blob/master/imageloader.h

https://compilr.com/donaldpherman/cube-opengl/imageloader.h

Comment: having the same problem. mind updating the content of said `imageloader.h`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is someone's custom image loading code, namely the person who posted that forum post.  The `imageloader.h` file will just be a header file for which the author has not included the source.  You could likely reconstruct it by defining a class called `Image` in a header file with the public methods as the ones listed in `imageloader.cpp`.